# Akka - Handling Blocking Operations

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, spray

I have an application built using Scala, Akka and Spray.
In the application I have a blocking call to an external bash script.
It is called via sys.process and takes on average about 100ms to run.

I've been testing the application using Curl & Apache Bench to get some performance metrics. I also time the sys.process call itself using nanoTime().

If I test using a single Curl call the application performs as expected, with the sys.process call taking about 100ms.

When I increase the load on the server by using Apache Bench with multiple simultaneous requests, the sys.process call starts to increase drastically from 100ms to close to 1000ms depending on load.

From reading the Scala docs I am thinking the problem here is that the blocking call is using all the available threads in the execution context and this is killing performance.

But how can I best cater for this?

I tried creating a custom execution context and wrapping the call in a blocking future...

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100))
val future = Future {
  blocking {
    sys.process.Process(...),
      new java.io.File("/var/...")).!!
  }
}
```

I then have to wait for the future to complete using onComplete but this in turn seems to block the threads and I can't see any noticeable increase in performance based on the number of requests per second Apache Bench is reporting.

The above code is in a method within an Actor class and is called by the receive method.

Can anyone recommend how should I structure this code to increase the number of threads and reduce the time spent in blocking code as much as possible? 
i.e. hand off the operation and return to it when it completes.

Thanks

Comment: It is weird. How do you use `onComplete`? Is there any `Await` statements in your code? Or is it possible this bash script to use some shared resource so its running time will increase when you run it in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would respond asynchronously to avoid the blocking behavior:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  val exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(max_threads)

  def recieve = {
    case Request(file) => {
      exec.submit(new Runnable() {
        def run() {
          sys.process.Process(...),
          new java.io.File("/var/...")).!!   
          self ! Done(file) // dont block, respond asynchronously
        }
      })
    }

    case Done(file) => completeRequest(file)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new thread for this.

```
class MyActor extends Actor {      
  def recieve = {
    case Request(file) => {
        val process=sys.process.Process.....
        self ! CheckProcess(process, file)
    }
    case CheckProcess(process, file)=>{
        if(doUppkeep(process)){
            self ! CheckProcess(process, file)
        } else {
            Done(file) 
        }
    }
    case Done(file) => completeRequest(file)
    }
  def doUpKeep(process):Boolean={
     // Do wathever is needed to keep the external process running
     // avoid looping since this pethod will be called again
     // return true if process is still running.
  }
}
```

If you want you can scedule the CheckProcess messages in stead of just pushing them to the message queue.

```
self.context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 milliseconds, self, CheckProcess(process, file))
```

This will make the process behave a bit nicer, but each request might become a little bit slower.

This pattern keeps the resources used to a minimum while making shure all processes get their atention.